# Clearing canvas causes the old content to re-appear on the next draw

Tags: html, canvas

I have a clear button which seems to work..but actually its not. When I click back on the canvas I can see the drawing.

Comment: you're setting:  canvas.width=canvas.width
Is that a typo? If not, that could be your problem.

Comment: No canvas.width = canvas.width works for IE9 to clear.

Comment: But it does not work for all browsers to clear (esp. Safari). Use of `clearRect()` is correct.

Comment: I can't view source atm (iPhone) but it strongly appears that you are not actually closing and beginning your paths correctly. This is why a stroke will "keep" information previously drawn. Your clear button is obviously working, but you re-draw the previous paths after clearing.

Comment: @Phrogz I checked all beginning and closing paths. I didn't miss any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem in the way you are clearing the canvas, the problem lies in your logic.

Everytime you `click` or move the mouse the `addClick` method is called, which populates the arrays `clickX`, `clickY` and `clickDrag` with the coordinates; and then the `redraw` method is called which plots the points on the `canvas`.

So when you clear the `canvas` you are failing to reset these arrays, so when the `redraw` method is called again (after clearing the canvas), the old points get plotted too.

So try emptying the arrays `clickX`, `clickY` and `clickDrag` as shown below, when you clear your `canvas`; so that the old points are not considered when you start fresh.

```
clickX = [];
clickY = [];
clickDrag = [];
```

Comment: If you don't clear the canvas before you `redraw` it will end up drawing over the same coordinates over and over again. Better just clear the canvas on redraw and reset the arrays only when the `Clear` button is pressed.

Comment: Thanks. Additionally I removed clearCanvas() from redraw() too. It works now.

Comment: This method does not work when you are working with multiple colors. The whole canvas reappears immediately when you click the mouse or touch the screen.

Comment: @CodeToGlory which method? this answer is a solution to dragonfly's specific problem.